# change color of bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove the pink color and set to transparent...the pink color is my scaffolds background color...how to do this?

```dart
    return Scaffold(
     
extendBody: true,
       // bottomNavigationBar:
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: 80,
          child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(80.0),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
          //  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
           // onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: 'Search',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'Profile',
              ),
            ],
          ),
              ),
        ),
     
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 7, 135),
```

[image]

Comment: Not necessary to ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the pink color from the background of your scaffold and make it transparent, try setting the scaffold's backgroundColor property to Colors.transparent. This makes the background of the scaffold completely transparent so that no color is displayed.

```
return Scaffold(
extendBody: true,
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
// Rest of your Scaffold content...
);
```

Hopefully, if you set backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, the background of the framework will be completely transparent.
If the pink color comes from other components or widgets within the framework, you may need to check and adjust their background colors as well to achieve your desired transparency.